# Tortoise SVN, how to get changes from server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I did the following on my workspace:

1. made some changes in a folder called "src" from my working copy;
2. renamed the "src" folder which contains the changes to "src-mine";
3. updated the working copy and get that renamed folder, "src", from server again; now I have "src" and "src-mine" two folders;
4. made some other changes in the folder "src" from above #3;
5. checked in the changes from above #4;
6. deleted "src" folder and rename the "src-mine" back to "src";
7. now the "src" should be different from the "src" on the repository; The local "src" has some changes the repository doesn't have; and the repository "src" has some changes the local src doesn't have;
8. did update and try to get the changes from #4 but Tortoise failed to grape the  changes from server;
9. tried command line update command, the same , nothing being updated from server; but we do have changes on the server;

how can I get the changes from server and merge them into my existing changed files?

Answer (score 0):

Your step #6 represents changes to the HEAD. And as far as SVN is concerned, your working copy is up to date with some locally changed files. The fact that some files represent a reverse of changes in HEAD is irrelevant.

Your changes in `src-mine` are based on a previous revision to HEAD.

You could create a branch at the previous revision, commit your `src-mine` changes to that branch (much in the same way as step #6), and then merge the branch back into HEAD.

*I have not tested this - so all caveats apply*

Comment: is there a way to change something in the local record of .svn to let SVN knows its src contains something new to local src?